# No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid potential bug?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, encryption-symmetric

If I SPAM `F5` eventually I will get

```
"RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid."
```

But then it will disappear if i refresh again. I tried both in local and production envoirment

And yes, i have a `app_key` which was generated with `php artisan key:generate` with the Cipher `AES-256-CBC`. I cannot for my life understand what is wrong.

I have also made sure all **vendors are updated**

Even if this is occurs 1/500 it still occurs.

Thanks